# Want to edit filename in django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UploadFileForm, EditFileName
from .models import Image


@login_required
def home(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "PUT":
        print(request.FILES)
        form2 = EditFileName(request, request.FILES)
        if form2.is_valid():
            username = request.user
            image = request.FILES["image"]
            image_text = form2.cleaned_data.get("image")
            obj = Image.objects.filter(id = ).update(
                image_text = image_text
            )
    else:
        form2 = EditFileName()
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.user)
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print(request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.user
            image_text = request.FILES["image"].name
            image = form.cleaned_data.get("image")
            obj = Image.objects.create(
                username=username,
                image_text=image_text,
                image=image
            )
            obj.save()
            print(obj)
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    context['form'] = form
    context['data'] = Image.objects.all()
    context['form2'] = form2
    print(context)
    return render(request, "registration/success.html", context)


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})
```

this is my views.py, i want to use `form2` to edit the filename of the image that i uploaded in `form`.

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms.fields import CharField


class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()


class EditFileName(forms.Form):
    filename = CharField(max_length=200)
```

this is my forms.py.

I just want a button to edit the filename, how do I do it?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anV6a.png)
This is how my template looks.

repo link - https://github.com/smrpn/task/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

I can help you rename the images name in models.

here how I change your code:

views.py

```
def rename_img(request):
   print(request.POST)
   pk = request.POST['img_id']
   img =Image.objects.get(pk=pk)
   img.image_text = request.POST['image_text']
   img.save()
   return redirect("/home")
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
...
path('rename/', views.rename_img, name='rename_img')
```

]

success.html

```
<form action='/rename/' method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="hidden" name="img_id" value={{question.pk}}>
          <input id="image_text" placeholder="{{question.image_text}}" type="text" name="image_text" maxlength="100">
          <input type="submit" value="Rename">
        </form>
```